# SQL Connection string issue in Visual Studio projects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with 7 Projects (6 Libraries and one EXE).
For Each project I used the Data Designer Wizard in Visual Studio to connect to a SQL DB on my remote server. 
This has  created an app.config for each project with a connection string to my remote DB.
All works fine on my dev environement.

No when I compiled and tried to run my app on a desktop PC which has SQL DB locally installed to it using the same name for the SQL Instance name, my app wouldnt run because the connection string is trying to lookup a DB on DBSERVER\DBINSTANCENAME.
Now I went and I changed the EXE.config file to DESKTOP\DBINSTANCENAME and tried running it again and the main app launched but any functionality from the lib projects failed with an exception cannot find the DB instance name.

this is how the app.config looks like:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`
`<configuration>`
`<connectionStrings>`
`<add name="Test" connectionString="MYSERVER\DBSERVER;Initial Catalog=DBINSTANCENAME;IntegratedSecurity=True"`providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
           
        `</configuration>`
    `

How can I resolve this ?

Thank you

Comment: You should start by showing what the string you are using is (replacing the sensitive info with placeholder text)

Comment: the app.config file is auto generated whenever I connect to a DB.

it looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="MYSERVER\DBSERVER;Initial Catalog=DBINSTANCENAME;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: your test server, was it a local connection or a remote? IT could be a port issue

Comment: my development was done on a client connecting remotely to a DB Server

Comment: `Server=192.168.1.82,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=mbc;User ID=user;Password=mypass` - This is an example of what I use for remote connections. I would strongly consider ports given your application cannot see the server. Most likely the server is being blocked by windows firewall

Comment: on my development it works fine connecting to the server. the problem is when I port my app to a desktop computer where the DB is also local to the desktop computer so there is no remote connection. The issue is that the projects are trying to look for my server DB and cannot make them read the config file, only the main projects (exe) reads it.

Comment: Update your question and paint a complete picture. Im a little confused as to the problem right now.

Comment: updated question hope this helps

Comment: oh wow. so uh. your database is on the same computer as the application is running? manually edit the app.config, replace `connectionString=.....` with `Data Source=(local)`, compile your application, then deploy it.

Comment: ok can the Data Source be a DSN and that way I dont have to rebuild it for each PC I would simply create an entry in ODBC DSN?

Comment: Yes. Refer [here](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings) for guidance on implementation

Comment: For local SQL Server you can use in connection server name ".\INSTANCE". Using "dot" instead of local server network name you tell sql client to connect over shared memory instead of loopback network adapter, it is much more performant way.